# Error when selecting an image in Media library

Tags: content-editor, media-library

I'm facing an issue where when I'm in the content editor clicking on some already uploaded images in the media library, then I get a popup with an error in it.

And when I go to the event viewer to see the logged error I get the following.

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 5/30/2018 12:10:33 PM 
Event time (UTC): 5/30/2018 10:10:33 AM 
Event ID: d503e129f07a4dbcaf238572566c50ed 
Event sequence: 8294 
Event occurrence: 3 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131721459236746399 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: D:\wwwroot\1.0.0.1545\ 
    Machine name: CM01 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 752 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: TargetInvocationException 
    Exception message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Failed to map the path '/temp/_disabled.'.
   at System.Web.Configuration.ProcessHostMapPath.MapPathCaching(String siteID, VirtualPath path)
   at System.Web.Configuration.ProcessHostMapPath.System.Web.Configuration.IConfigMapPath2.MapPath(String siteID, VirtualPath path)
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPathActual(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean permitNull)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, VirtualPath baseVirtualDir, Boolean allowCrossAppMapping)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.MapPath(String path)
   at Sitecore.Resources.Themes.GetFilename(String source, String size, String overlay, Boolean disabled)
   at Sitecore.Resources.Themes.Transform(String source, String overlay, Boolean disabled)
   at Sitecore.Resources.Themes.MapTheme(String sourcePath, String overlay, Boolean disabled)
   at Sitecore.Resources.ImageBuilder.ToString()
   at Sitecore.Shell.Web.UI.WebControls.SmallGalleryButton.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderSmallButton(HtmlTextWriter output, Control smallButton)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderSmallGalleryButton(HtmlTextWriter output, Item button, CommandContext commandContext)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderButton(HtmlTextWriter output, Item button, CommandContext commandContext)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunk(HtmlTextWriter output, Item chunk, CommandContext commandContext)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunk(HtmlTextWriter output, Item chunk, CommandContext commandContext, Boolean isContextual, String id)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunk(HtmlTextWriter output, Item chunk, CommandContext commandContext, Boolean isContextual)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunks(HtmlTextWriter output, Item strip, CommandContext commandContext, Boolean isContextual)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderStrips(HtmlTextWriter output, Item ribbon, Boolean isContextual, ListString visibleStripList)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderStrips(HtmlTextWriter output, Item defaultRibbon, Item contextualRibbon, ListString visibleStripList)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at Sitecore.Web.HtmlUtil.RenderControl(Control ctl)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.UpdateRibbon(Item folder, Boolean isCurrentItemChanged, Boolean showEditor)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.Update()
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.OnPreRendered(EventArgs e)


Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 89 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

It's not on all images and the person that has uploaded the images can click on them without getting the error.

The version is: Sitecore.NET 8.2 (rev. 171121)

Comment: Check if `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` account has access to `'/temp/.'` folder. It should be allowed to create new folders and files there.

Comment: It has "Full control" and every checkbox under "Allow" is checked

Comment: Do you have `_disabled.` in your config? with `.` at the end?

Comment: I can't find any config file containing `_disabled` with or without `.`

Comment: ensure you have relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" parameter in "httpRuntime" node of the "web.config"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's a bug in sitecore or not, but the problem was that an image was uploaded by a user and it was still in draft state in the workflow, so when a person other than the one owning the draft clicked on it, it would fail. as soon as that person moved it for approval, it stopped failing.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar kind of issue today where one particular author was able to see a CSS file item in the media library and others are not able to click on that item. When others clicked on the item they got the error `Failed to map the path /temp/_disabled.`

I analyzed the issue and found that the item is locked by one author, and because of that it was causing the issue. I asked them to unlock the item and doing so resolved the issue.

Hope this will help someone.